# How to extract multiple substrings in a string using stringr regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have this string:

```
mystring <- "HMSC-bm_in_ALL_CELLTYPES.distal"
```

What I want to do is to extract the substring as defined
in this bracketing

```
[HMSC-bm]_in_ALL_CELLTYPES.[distal]
```

So in the end it will yield a vector with two values: `HMSC-bm` and `distal`. How can I do it? I tried this but failed:

```
> stringr::str_extract(base,"\\([\\w-]+\\)_in_ALL_CELLTYPES\\.\\([\\w+]\\)")
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `str_match`:

```
library(stringr)
mymatch <- str_match(mystring, "^(.*?)_.*?\\.(.*?)$")
mymatch

     [,1]                              [,2]      [,3]    
[1,] "HMSC-bm_in_ALL_CELLTYPES.distal" "HMSC-bm" "distal"

mymatch[, 2]
[1] "HMSC-bm"

mymatch[3, ]
[1] "distal"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can split the string by `_in_ALL_CELLTYPES.`.

```
strsplit(mystring, split = "_in_ALL_CELLTYPES.")[[1]]
[1] "HMSC-bm" "distal"
```